# How do I temporarily turn off instances in an autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I don't wnat to terminate my asg and I dont want to terminate the instances.

Is it possible to turn off instances in an asg and not have the asg spawn more instances?

I believe if i turn off the instances the asg spawned it would terminate them and start new ones right?

Comment: By "turn off" in the second sentence, do you actually mean remove from the ASG?  Please be precise in your use of the terms terminate, turn off, and possibly remove from ASG, as the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [suspend and resume the scaling processes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html).

Take a look at suspending the *Launch* and *Terminate* processes.

Comment: So I could suspend the scaling process first, then shut off the instances? And the instances wont be terminated and the asg wont start new ones?

Comment: By "shut off", presumably you mean 'stop'. You're probably going to need to suspend additional processes related to health in that case. Give it a try with a small autoscaling group and test it out.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling either **launches new instances** or **terminates instances**. It does not support the concept of **stopping** instances for later restart.

There is, however, the ability to [detach an instance from an Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/detach-instances.html). This stops Auto Scaling from doing anything with the instance and, optionally, decreases the **desired count** of instances in the Auto Scaling group (meaning it would not be replaced).

You could then do whatever you want with the instance, such as stopping it. You could later start it again and then [attach the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/attach-instances.html) to the Auto Scaling group again.

However, this is against the recommended way that Auto Scaling works. By using the **default launch/terminate behaviour**, Auto Scaling can add as many instances as necessary and can launch replacement instances in a different Availability Zone in case an AZ fails.

If you use the **detach/attach method**, then *you* will be responsible for ensuring the availability of instances to meet your application's needs, which rather defeats the purpose of using Auto Scaling.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct - instances will be replaced in your ASG to fulfill the min, max and desired attributes.

You can scale your ASG down to zero instances via the min, max and desired attributes. However, that will terminate the instances in the ASG.
I'm not sure you can scale down an ASG and preserve the instances without removing those instances from the ASG first and then shutting them down. Then maybe you can add them back into the ASG when desired.